# use Grouper to group rows by datetime frequency and plot count of another column (with reproduction code)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, visualization

for simplicity, lets say i have a dataframe the following arrangement:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def random_dates(start, end, n, unit='D', seed=None):
    if not seed:  
        np.random.seed(0)

    ndays = (end - start).days + 1
    return pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(n) * ndays, unit=unit) + start
np.random.seed(0)
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
date = random_dates(start, end, 1000)
#%%
gender = np.random.randint(0,2,(1000,))
DF = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_of_call':date,'gender_of_caller':gender})
```

i want to plot the distribution of male and female callers to some line, as a function of year/month/hour ON TOTAL (separately, we can say just month for now)

for example, i want to see visually that **irrespective of year**, specifically on January there is a high fraction of female callers. another example would be if i want the frequency to be per hour, so i want to know the distribution of male/female throughout all years only by the hour.

i used grouper to group according to month:

```
DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime_of_call',freq='M'))
```

now not sure how to continue, i tried the following:

```
pd.crosstab(DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime_of_call',freq='M')),DF.gender_of_caller).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

but got an error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (37, 2), indices imply (1000, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with `groupby` and `to_period`

```
gb = DF.groupby(['gender_of_caller', DF.datetime_of_call.dt.to_period('M')]).size()
df = gb.unstack()
```

gets you a dataframe like:
[image]

Then you can take its transpose with

```
df = df.T
```

[image]

And then you can plot this as a bar chart or something:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

EDIT: If you want the group by to be the month regardless of the year you can change the `groupby` line to:

```
gb = DF.groupby(['gender_of_caller', DF.datetime_of_call.dt.month]).size()
```

Now the final graph will look like:
[image]

Comment: this is not exactly what i'm trying to do, i want only the month, so if an instance belongs to the same month but in another year it will be summed under that month

Comment: ah i see. check the edited answer - the month irrespective of the year can be achieved by modifying the groupby parameters

Comment: is it possible to normalize and stack them on top of each other such that for each hour you would have only one bar with fraction of each gender?

Comment: you can make a stacked bar chart by changing the `plot` function call to `df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`. There are a ton of options in the pandas plot command that may be useful for you: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html